# How to pause ffmpeg than runs without window?

Tags: vb.net, ffmpeg, backgroundworker, sendkeys, pausing-execution

I'm working on a video converter and I wanted to be able to stop or pause ffmpeg by pressing a button. Googleing I have found a way but it's not working. basically I Start ffmpeg on a background worker in this way:

```
Private Sub bw_DoWork(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DoWorkEventArgs)

        Dim Proc As New Process

        Proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = True
        Proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
        Proc.StartInfo.FileName = current_ffmpeg_path
        Proc.StartInfo.Arguments = input_params
        Proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
        Proc.Start()

[do things...]
```

then inside a loop I place an if to pause ffmpeg:

```
If (pause = 1 Or pause = 2) Then
        AppActivate(Proc.Id)
        SendKeys.SendWait("^(s)")
        SetForegroundWindow(Me)
        pause = 0
    End If
```

but it's not working.. maybe cause of AppActivate that need a window to work while instead ffmpeg is running without it. There is another way? maybe not with sendkeys?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VB.NET: How to maintain main form control during loops in other sub?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28265331/vb-net-how-to-maintain-main-form-control-during-loops-in-other-sub)

Comment: no it's another question... how can i send key to program without window??

Comment: noone can help me? i have found only a way to close ffmpeg but by process.kill()... i need to send command to properly close or pause ffmpeg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED. It's not possible use SendKeys for a process without a window.. use instead NtSuspendProcess and NtResumeProcess..

More information googling about:

p/invoke NtResumeProcess/NtSuspendProcess which are callable platform APIs